# SQL / Crystal record select

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

My SQL is rusty, and I cant figure this one out.

I have a table with a Year Field, then a series of Period x fields.
So the date would look like

```
YEAR     PERIOD1      PERIOD2  ...  PERIOD12
2014     100          200           300
2015     200          300           400
```

My problem is , to create a financial year, I need Period `1-7 from 2015 and 8-12 from 2015`.

I will be buggered, if I can either write a select statement to give me this or write a formula field in Crystal to give me the `SUM` of these periods.

Any ideas would be awesome..

Comment: in your data does not show 1-7 or 8-12 portion.. how to bifurgate?

Comment: instead of writing Periods 1 to 12, use .... to show they are all the same format....

Comment: not understand clearly, could you give us input data and output data layout in table or excel format or image to understand more.

Answer (score 1):

Your question mentioned both period ranges coming from 2015. If that is indeed the case, you can add the period fields per row.

However if the financial year 2015 is defined by periods 1-7 from 2015 and periods 8-12 from *2014*, you could approach it like below.

Given a sample setup in Oracle, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl
    (year int, period1 int, period2 int, period3 int, period4 int, period5 int, period6 int, period7 int, period8 int, period9 int, period10 int, period11 int, period12 int);

INSERT ALL 
    INTO tbl (year, period1, period2, period3, period4, period5, period6, period7, period8, period9, period10, period11, period12)
         VALUES (2014, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200)
    INTO tbl (year, period1, period2, period3, period4, period5, period6, period7, period8, period9, period10, period11, period12)
         VALUES (2015, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200, 1300)
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

You could normalize the data with several "union all" statements. Once normalized, the data can be queried easier, and a case statement could be applied to make the split by period range for financial year, like so:

```
select case when period between '08' and '12' then year + 1
            when period between '01' and '07' then year
            else null
       end fin_year,
       sum(amount) amount
  from (select year, '01' period, period1  amount from tbl union all
        select year, '02' period, period2  amount from tbl union all
        select year, '03' period, period3  amount from tbl union all
        select year, '04' period, period4  amount from tbl union all
        select year, '05' period, period5  amount from tbl union all
        select year, '06' period, period6  amount from tbl union all
        select year, '07' period, period7  amount from tbl union all
        select year, '08' period, period8  amount from tbl union all
        select year, '09' period, period9  amount from tbl union all
        select year, '10' period, period10 amount from tbl union all
        select year, '11' period, period11 amount from tbl union all
        select year, '12' period, period12 amount from tbl
       )
group by case when period between '08' and '12' then year + 1
              when period between '01' and '07' then year
              else null
         end;
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can return the periods in an order of course (or just add them all up) and alias them any way that's convenient.

```
select t1.PERIOD8 + ... t1.PERIOD12 + t2.PERIOD1 + t2.PERIOD2, + ... t1.PERIOD7
from T as t1 inner join T as t2 on t2.YEAR = t1.YEAR + 1
where t1.YEAR = 2014;
```

I imagine this is probably faster than a bunch of unions although I like the idea of being able to treat all the data in a single column.

Comment: I tried this....
select t1.PERIOD8 + t1.PERIOD9 + t1.PERIOD10 + t1.PERIOD11 + t1.PERIOD12 + t2.PERIOD1 + t2.PERIOD2
from  EMPLACTUAL_FBL_YEAR_V as t1
inner join EMPLACTUAL_FBL_YEAR_V as t2 on t2.YEAR = t1.YEAR + 1
where t1.YEAR = '2014'

Keep getting ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: yes....
 the SQL command not properly ended....
even if I put a group by or order by at the end, I still get the same error.

Comment: Do you need a semicolon? You didn't say which platform this is. Nevermind, it's Oracle.